# Getting invalid literal for int() with base 10. while converting str into int

Tags: python, string, integer

I am trying to convert a string into int but facing some difficulty. how to over come this?

```
random_image=['12.jpg']
s1=str(random_image)[1:-1].replace(".jpg", "")
s2=int(s1)
```

Comment: Break the second line into multiple steps, and print the result for each step. That should make it obvious where things go wrong, or at least give you input for a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to extract the file name from the list. That's easy as its the first and only item. Then you can slice off the last 4 chars of extension and convert to an integer:

```py
random_image = ['12.jpg']
s1=int(random_image[0][:-4])
print(s1)
```

Output

```
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1=str(random_image)[1:-1].replace("'",'').strip(".jpg")
s2=int(s1)
```

You can try this

Comment: its is not working; it is giving invalid syntax error

Comment: @acousticpython check it now, missing parentheses

Answer (score 0):

`str(random_image)` evaluates to the *string* `['12.jpg']`, so you need to strip *two* chars off the front and back before replacing the `.jpg`.  Why are you explicitly calling `str`?